# Как создать русское меню в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css

```
Не могу создать меню на русском в wordpress 3.4 (сам вордпресс русский, с офиц. сайта).  Если значения текст ссылки меню указываю на английском, то всё нормально создаётся. Но если указывать на русском языке, то на сайте ничего не высвечивается (просто идёт как пустой пункт меню).

Когда я добавляю к русскому слову какой нибудь символ (скажем круглую скобку), то в пункте меню эта только скобка и остаётся, а всё русское слово вырезается. 
Использую шаблон locus (в нём то и вся загвоздка, так как на других шаблонах русское меню отображается нормально). Может кто сталкивался с подобным и как это решается?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ прост, как никогда: **UTF-8**.

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: В шаблоне в header.php у меня уже прописано кодировка utf-8 и не работает. Помимо шаблонного header.php ещё надо где небудь прописывать? Неужили дело в кодировке? Я думаю еслибы кодировка была неправильной, оно бы выводило русский, только искарёженно, а так оно вообще русские слова вырезает и ничего не выводит

Comment: Вставьте русский текст вручную, т.е. меняя код.

Comment: В шаблоне header.php вот элементы отвечающие за меню 
<div id="menu">
<?php locus_nav(); ?>
</div> 

Функция locau_vav загружает ещё одну функцию, а та в свою очередь wp_nav_menu.  
Немного не могу найти где вручную можно было прописать название пунктов меню?

Comment: Как выглядит html код в отрезке между <div id="menu">  </div> *при просмотре в браузере*

Comment: <div id="menu">
    <ul id="menu-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e1" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-879" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-879"><a href="#home">(Главная)</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-880"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-889" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-889"><a href="#contact">Contactus</a></li>
</ul>    </div>
  </div>

Странно что слово Главная в html есть, но на сайте его не выводит

Comment: 1) Попробуйте отключить css и посмотреть эту страницу 2) Тоже самое с javascript

Comment: отключил джаваскрипт cufon.yui.js и всё нормально выводит. Спасибо за помощь, там в js я уже сам разберусь.